# Why am I getting a "Function not defined" error when trying to run JavaScript function in Laravel 10?

Tags: javascript, laravel

I'm working on a Laravel project and have trouble getting my JavaScript to run.
Just for testing purposes, I wrote a function called "ShowAlert", which are supposed to just display a simple alert screen with an OK button. But when I click the button to run this function, it shows the following error in the console:
Uncaught ReferenceError: ShowAlert is not defined

I have two separate JS files, one is the standard "app.js" which is located in the resources/js folder. In the same folder, I created a separate file called "mycode.js". My app.js file looks like this:

```
import './bootstrap';
import './mycode.js';
```

In the mycode.js file, I created the function using the window object, since I've read that JS code sometimes is not found because it has been written in the wrong scope. I don't know if I'm doing this write, please tell me in that case. :)
The mycode.js file looks like the following:

```
window.ShowAlert = function()
{
    alert("Hello world!");
    }
```

Here is the head of the resources/views/layouts.app file which imports the JavaScript:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- CSRF Token -->
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

    <title>{{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}</title>

    <!-- Fonts -->
    <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//fonts.bunny.net">
    <link href="https://fonts.bunny.net/css?family=Nunito" rel="stylesheet">
        <!-- Scripts -->
    @vite(['resources/sass/app.scss', 'resources/js/app.js'])

    
      
</head>
```

In a separate view, which extends the layout file above, I am calling the JS function like this:

```
<button onclick="ShowAlert()">Show alert</button>
```

Any help with this will be greatly appreciated!

All the best!

Comment: Look in your browser debug window to see if `import './mycode.js';` is actually including that file perhaps.  Is it in another folder or location that serves static files for you?

Answer (score 0):

First, you can import files to app.js without the extension, just a tip:

```
import './mycode';
```

I tried to replicate your issue, but it works just fine, for the JS function I did it like this:

```
window.ShowAlert = () => {
    alert('Hello World');
}
```

Using a button like yours:

```
<button onclick="ShowAlert()">Show Alert</button>
```

For me, I repeat, it's working fine. Make sure you're running Vite:

```
npm run dev
```

The only way I could replicate your problem was trying to run it without Vite running, and took me a few minutes cause at first, I didn't even consider it as a possibility. If you want to build your app instead of constantly have Vite running, what I don't recommend in development for obvious reasons, you can try:

```
npm run build
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I tried to modify the JS function call like you did but unfortunately, I got the same result. :(
When I run "npm run dev", I get the following:
VITE v4.4.8 ready in 652 ms

➜ Local: http://localhost:5173/
➜ Network: use --host to expose
➜ press h to show help

LARAVEL v10.17.1 plugin v0.7.8

➜ APP_URL: http://localhost

It looks good to me, but maybe I'm doing something wrong?

All the best!

Comment: Put a `console.log('something')` in your JS file and check in the browser console if the text appears in it just to make sure the JS files are being imported correctly. If you have vite running, it should appear as soon as you refresh the page.

Comment: Thanks! I've tried this but I don't see any text in the console. :( Maybe it is something with Vite, but I have no idea what it could be. :)

Comment: For testing purposes, I put the console.log function inside a <script> tag directly in my blade view and that worked, I didn't even ran "npm run dev". So maybe it is something going wrong when it imports the js file?

Comment: Yes, your JS files aren't being imported correctly. Check your vite config file, double check you have your JS file correctly imported into the `app.js` file. In your blade file, ensure you're extending the main layout. Just double check everything.

Comment: try to put the button directly into the `app.blade.php` in your layouts folder, check if that works. If so, check you're extending the layout to your blade view.

Comment: I am ashamed right now! I am still quite new to npm and have not really got my head around how it works yet. I didn't realize that after running "npm run dev", I need to keep the window open since it is running a server, and open a separate command prompt window to run "php artisan serve". When I do that, everything works perfectly of course. I'm so sorry for bothering you with this and thank you so much for your time and effort! Wish you all the best!

Answer (score 0):

change javascript code like:

```
function ShowAlert() {
 alert('alert text');
}
```